# How does two read operations on the same segment at the same time work in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: concurrency, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to understand how read operation works internally in HashTable, HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap.
ConcurrentHashMap is internally divided into segments of size 32. So at max 32 threads can read at a time.   What happens when we get two read operations on the same segment at the same time in ConcurrentHashMap.

Also, I would like to know how multiple read on the same element work in HashTable, HashMap?

Comment: *In the past*, i.e. before Java 8, the `ConcurrentHashMap` used a *configurable number of segments*, not “segments of size 32”.

Answer (score 1):

> ConcurrentHashMap is internally divided into segments of size 32. So at max 32 threads can read at a time.

That is not correct. According to [the ConcurrentHashMap documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), "retrieval operations do *not* entail locking" [emphasis in original]. This means that arbitrarily many threads can read the map at a time. (Note: the above link is to the documentation for the latest version of Java, but the same is true of all versions. The above-quoted statement been there since [the documentation for JDK 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), which was the initial version where ConcurrentHashMap was introduced.)

Even for updates, which *do* involve locking, this statement isn't true: ConcurrentHashMap has not been partitioned into "segments" since Java 7; back when it *was* partitioned into segments, what mattered for concurrency was the *number* of segments, not their *size*; the number of segments was user-configurable; and the default number of segments was 16, not 32.

> Also, I would like to know how multiple read on the same element work in HashTable, HashMap?

Hashtable.get locks the entire map, so it doesn't matter whether concurrent reads are of the same element or different ones; either way, one locks out the other.

HashMap doesn't worry about concurrency; multiple threads can happily read the map at the same time, but it's not safe to have updates concurrently with reads or other updates.